How do I make a UserDefaults publisher behave consistently with multiple threads?
I am currently working on a system communicating some UserDefaults values to another system on change. I was trying to use UserDefaults.standard.publisher as seen in the example below to observe changes on a specific value, but did not even receive updates. I then started experimenting with UserDefaults a multiple threads to see if it is actually thread-safe as Apples documentation claims. I have constructed the following example below and cannot seem to find an explanation for the behaviour. My question now is how do I make the publisher always receive updated values and be thread safe?
Example Code
import Combine
import Foundation

let key = "value"

private extension UserDefaults {
    
    @objc dynamic var value: Int {
        get { integer(forKey: key) }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: key) }
    }
}

print("Starting")

let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup.enter()
dispatchGroup.enter()

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    
    UserDefaults.standard.value = 0

    let publisher = UserDefaults.standard.publisher(for: \.value, options: .new)

    let cancellable = publisher.sink { value in
        print("Received: \(value)")
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.value = 1
    
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(2, forKey: key)

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(3, forKey: key)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

dispatchGroup.wait()

print("Finished")


Output
Starting
Received: 1
Received: 1
Received: 2
Finished


Your output looks correct to me. Before the async code that sets the value to 3 runs the outer DispatchQueue.global().async block has finished and there is no longer anything attached to the publisher

Also, I don't believe that your code establishes whether UserDefaults is thread safe or not. DispatchQueues are not threads. There is a very good chance that all of your code is executing on the main thread. Async dispatching can introduce ambiguity into the order of execution, particularly when I/O is involved,  but that isn't what thread safety is about.

That makes sense, thanks for the explanation. Would you have any idea why the publisher would not fire at all under any circumstances? This is the current behaviour in the application I am working on.

The problem has nothing to do with the thread that is changing the value. As you noted, UserDefaults is thread-safe.
The real issue stems from the computed property:

We see duplicative events when we use the computed property because there are two independent sources of the KVO notifications:

The computed property in the UserDefaults extension; and
The setting of a value in UserDefaults via set(_:forKey:) will also generate a KVO notification.

Thus, UserDefaults.standard.value = 1 will result in these two independent notifications.

Regarding why you do not see the duplicative events when one bypasses the computed property and use UserDefaults/NSObject method setValue(_:forKey:) directly, that is because setValue bypasses the Swift setter.


The net effect of these two observations is that this …
UserDefaults.standard.value = 0

… will result in the two KVO notifications, whereas …
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(1, forKey: key)

… will result in only one (namely, the UserDefaults own KVO notification mechanisms, and not your custom setter).

So, let us look at a simplified example with some additional diagnostics. Notably, I will excise the use of the dispatch queues. I also removed the DispatchGroup and the use of wait (which is an anti-pattern, anyway):
let key = "value"

private extension UserDefaults {
    @objc dynamic var value: Int {
        get { integer(forKey: key) }
        set {
            print("setting 'value' to \(newValue)")
            set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

class Experiment {
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    func startPublisher() {
        UserDefaults.standard
            .publisher(for: \.value, options: .new)
            .sink { value in
                print("Received: \(value)")
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func update() {
        UserDefaults.standard.value = 0
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(1, forKey: key)
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(2, forKey: key)

        print("Finished")
    }
}

So, assuming we call startPublisher first, every subsequent time we call update, it will produce:
setting 'value' to 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 1
Received: 2
Finished

Note, the setter in that extension is getting called only once, where we use the UserDefaults.standard.value = 0 syntax. And when you use this syntax, you see two events, the setter for this dynamic property, and the KVO notification from UserDefaults, itself.
For giggles and grins, consider a change of the UserDefaults key to be something other than the key path for your value property (which is #keyPath(value)):
let key = "foo"

With that change, UserDefaults will perform KVO notifications for "foo", but our dynamic computed property will continue to perform KVO notifications for "value" (the property’s #keyPath).
With this simple change of the UserDefault key, our publisher on \.value will only detect direct calls to our custom setter, and will not detect the interaction with UserDefaults via setValue(_:forKey:).
setting 'value' to 0
Received: 0
Finished


For illustrative purposes, note that one can turn off automatic KVO notifications for your custom property by overriding automaticallyNotifiesObservers(for:). (I’ve renamed the property to foo in this example, to avoid confusion between standard NSObject functions with value in their names.)
extension UserDefaults {
    @objc var foo: Int {
        get { integer(forKey: #keyPath(foo)) }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: #keyPath(foo)) }
    }

    open override class func automaticallyNotifiesObservers(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        if key == #keyPath(foo) {
            return false
        } else {
            return super.automaticallyNotifiesObservers(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

And then:
class Experiment {
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    func startPublisher() {
        UserDefaults.standard
            .publisher(for: \.foo, options: .new)
            .sink { foo in
                print("Received: \(foo)")
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func update() {
        UserDefaults.standard.foo = 0
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(1, forKey: #keyPath(UserDefaults.foo))
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(2, forKey: #keyPath(UserDefaults.foo))

        print("Finished")
    }
}

That will avoid the duplicative KVO notification of the foo property, relying solely on the notifications generated when UserDefaults updates its store:
Received: 0
Received: 1
Received: 2
Finished

I must confess that I do not like the idea of overriding a function in an extension of a Foundation class. That makes too many assumptions about the internal implementation of UserDefaults. I would generally only override functions from within subclasses (but we probably do not want to subclass UserDefaults). I only include this example as an illustration of what is going on, that the custom property is generating KVO notifications (which I turned off in this final example), on top of the notifications emitted by UserDefaults when it updates its store.

Another approach would be to create a publisher on UserDefaults.didChangeNotification rather than on KVO notifications for the property keypath:
extension UserDefaults {
    func publisher<T: Equatable>(_ type: T.Type = T.self, forKey key: String) -> AnyPublisher<T, Never> {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: self)
            .compactMap { _ in self.value(forKey: key) as? T }
            .removeDuplicates()            // this is needed because `didChangeNotification` does not supply the key for the value that changed, and we do not want to generate unnecessary notifications for this key if some other value changed
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

private extension UserDefaults {
    var value: Int {                       // `@objc` and `dynamic` no longer necessary
        get { integer(forKey: key) }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: key) }
    }
}

And then:
class Experiment {
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    func startPublisher() {
        UserDefaults.standard
            .publisher(Int.self, forKey: key)
            .sink { value in
                print("Received: \(value)")
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func update() {
        UserDefaults.standard.value = 0
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(1, forKey: key)
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(2, forKey: key)

        print("Finished")
    }
}

That will produce:
Received: 0
Received: 1
Received: 2
Finished

By using UserDefaults.didChangeNotification instead, we avoid this KVO key collision. Furthermore, because our computed property is no longer @objc, it does not emit any KVO notifications at all.

Another approach is to use different keys for the property and the UserDefaults store. By using a different, opaque key in the UserDefaults store, it will make it hard for app developers to accidentally bypass the computed property and interacting directly with the opaque key used by UserDefaults store. By making the UserDefaults key something that is private and opaque, we avoid unintentional key name collisions.
Thus, we encourage interaction with this custom UserDefaults key-value pair only via our custom computed property, hiding the key used in the store:
extension UserDefaults {
    private static let fooUserDefaultsKey = "__CustomUserDefaultsKey." + #keyPath(foo)

    @objc var foo: Int {
        get { integer(forKey: Self.fooUserDefaultsKey) }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: Self.fooUserDefaultsKey) }
    }
}

And:
class Experiment {
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    func startPublisher() {
        UserDefaults.standard
            .publisher(for: \.foo, options: .new)
            .sink { foo in
                print("Received: \(foo)")
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func update() {
        UserDefaults.standard.foo = 0
        UserDefaults.standard.foo = 1
        UserDefaults.standard.foo = 2

        // This discourages the bypassing of custom computed property and
        // directly interacting with the `UserDefaults` store: In this example,
        // the app developer does not have access to the opaque key used by the
        // computed property because it is declared as `private`. Thus, if the
        // app developer attempted to bypass the computed property, they have
        // no `key` of which they can readily avail themselves in the following:
        //
        // UserDefaults.standard.setValue(1, forKey: ???)
        // UserDefaults.standard.setValue(2, forKey: ???)

        print("Finished")
    }
}

This is still not ideal (as app developers could still theoretically dig through the code and figure out what the key actually used within the UserDefaults store; but then again, if they start using a __ prefixed key value, they clearly know that they are playing around with internal implementations at their own risk). This strikes me as the “least bad” solution for typed custom computed properties of UserDefaults.
The net effect is that we can observe KVO notifications only from our custom property, avoiding collisions with the UserDefaults store KVO notifications that would use that opaque key.

If removeDuplicates is acceptable, then we could have just used it for the previous setup and that would have been enough to remove the duplicate. You have not actually explained why calling value = x emits two values even though the value was set only once. This really seems to be a bug in the system somewhere. Note that if you make the setter an empty block, you still get the notification when assigning value a (even though the value doesn't update)

“You have not actually explained why calling value = x emits two values” … See point 1, above. There are two completely different KVO notification mechanisms. One is initiated by setting of any objc property of UserDefaults. The other is initiated by setting a value for any key in the UserDefaults store. So, the OP’s computed property does both, resulting in the duplicative events.

“If removeDuplicates is acceptable, then we could have just used it for the previous setup” … Yes, theoretically you could, but to my eye, it suggests a misunderstanding of how KVO notifications work. Why make the @objc property which will trigger the duplicative KVO notification, only to then turn around and removeDuplicates? I confess that I don’t like having to use the kludgy removeDuplicates in conjunction with UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, but this is a common work-around the fact that this notification inexplicably doesn’t include the key associated with the notification.

@Rob Thanks for the thorough answer! You seem to know a lot about the internal workings of UserDefaults and KVO Notifications. Would you have any idea why the NSObject Publisher using .publisher(for:, options:) would not fire at all under some circumstances? This is the current behaviour in the application I am working on. Listening to UserDefaults.didChangeNotification  works for this case, but seems not ideal as to my knowledge this method might not catch updates from extensions or other threads.

The one scenario that leaps to mind is if (a) the key being used in the UserDefaults store does not exactly match the “key path” for your custom property; and (b) if you update UserDefaults directly, bypassing your custom property. If you make sure these keys always match (and probably turning off property KVO via automaticallyNotifiesObservers) that will mitigate that scenario. Personally, I still would lean to the final approach, namely do all interaction via the computed properties, have them use opaque UserDefaults keys. Then the dev can’t bypass your properties.

I might take that final approach one step further: Rather than have these properties be extensions on UserDefaults, have your own type for them (but go ahead and use UserDefaults, or whatever you want, for your custom type’s backing store). That would further discourage devs from thinking about “well, this is in UserDefaults, so let me use UserDefaults’ standard interface.” (This also begs the question as to whether you are using UserDefaults for persistent storage of things that really aren't “user settings/defaults”.)


I have constructed the following example below and cannot seem to find an explanation for the behaviour.

When the first async block exits, the cancellable goes out of scope and the subscription ends. Then, the second async block executes which sets the value to 3 and releases the dispatch group.
You can see this if you declare the cancellable at the top level:
var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

and assign to it:
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    cancellable = publisher.sink { value in
        print("Combine Received: \(value)")
    }
    // ...

Then you will get the output:
Starting
Received: 1
Received: 1
Received: 2
Received: 3
Finished


As to why it receives the value 1 twice... I have no idea.

Thanks! It fires twice because the standard value for the options parameter is [.initial, .new] meaning it will also publish the initial value.

That may be the standard value, but the publisher is observing with just the .new parameter... The initial value is 0 which is never printed.
